# How to estimate the series resistance for this zener regulation?

Tags: zener

There is a variable load that draws current between 1mA up to 1.5A.
I want to supply the load with almost constant 4.2V(precision not improtant).
If I only have 5V supply I thought I can perform the regulation as follows:

[image]

But how can a proper Rs be calculated in this case? Or will this never work?

Comment: Why not a 5V regulator and a series diode?

Comment: _"precision not improtant"_ - 5V is only 19% higher than 4.2V, so...

Answer (score 2):

To get 4.2V from 5V, that doesn't have to be too accurate, a series silicon diode would put you right in the same ball park.  It would have to dissipate the same power as the LDO in Stiddly's answer.

Answer (score 1):

For 1.5A to go into your load you'd need an Rs of (5-4.2)/1.5 = .53 Ohm. Then calculate the Pd in the Zener at low load. You'd still have that 1.5A flowing through the zener now  so Pd is 1.5A*4.2V = 6.3W... That's a lot.

Meanwhile, an LDO would have a maximum power loss of 0.8V*1.5A = 1.2W. 4.2V isn't a standard value, but an adjustable 5V would do just fine.

Comment: Thanks for the warning, would this then work for my purpose?: http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lp3966.pdf It says Fast LDO Voltage Regulator, 3A Adjustable, 1.2 → 5 V,